# Wrapping contents of Row widget if overflowed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list storing the asset image location. Using that list I display those many cards of certain width side by side inside a website.

When the items in list increases, the row overflows. I want those cards to appear below, To have rest of cards in another line.

I'm returning this row to a singleChildScrollView parent widget.

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
   children: ProjectData.map((item) => Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 320, maxWidth: 240),
                child: Card(
                  child: Image.asset(item.fileLoc),
           ),
       )).toList(),
    ),
```

This row sits under a Column() widget and this entire Column is returned to a SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: What do you want to happen? You want to scroll in order to see the rest of the list, or you want the list to expand across multiple lines? Posting a picture or a diagram of your current layout may help, and not just the inner Row.

Comment: I want them to move to the next line.

Comment: Hey @KaranOwalekar check the answer out, it has the best use case as per your scenario. Feel free to check it out, and share your valuable feedback on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Wrap widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html):

> A widget that displays its children in multiple horizontal or vertical runs.

In your case, you can use as follows:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent cards
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: ProjectData.map((item) => Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 320, maxWidth: 240),
                child: Card(
                  child: Image.asset(item.fileLoc),
           ),
       )).toList(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! for your efforts :)

Comment: One more thing, Can we specify number of elements to be shown in one line ?

Comment: You can use `GridView` and set its `crossAxisCount` to the number of elements in each line. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html @KaranOwalekar

Comment: I'm usung singleChildScrollView as the parent widget, so it throws an error.

Comment: You'll need to set the `shrinkWrap` property of the `GridView` widget to `true` @KaranOwalekar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridView class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html), since, you can keep count of the item you want to show in per row. Basically `GridView.count()` is the one for you.

> To control the number of items in it, the power will be given by `crossAxisCount`

- Do not forget to give height to the `GridView()`, else, you will see a lot of errors coming up. It needs a parent height
- We are passing the item as `arrayname.map((item) => Your_Widget()).toList().cast<Widget>()`
- I have used my `myArray` for dummy show purpose. Feel free to use yours. The idea is to give you the best possible option
- In case you wanna explore [SingleChildScrollView class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) it will come in handy

```
     LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, // here you keep track of count
                  children: myArray.map((item) => Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15.0),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 320, maxWidth: 240),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
                    )
                  )).toList().cast<Widget>()
                )
              )
            )
          );
        }
      )
```

**Result**

[image: Result GIF]

Feel free to try it out.